# How to get a single user data from firestore without future builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this in my Auth Controller

```
  Future<Member?> readLoggedMemberonly() async {
    final User? user = Auth().currentUser;
    final mid = user?.uid;
    final docMember =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(mid.toString());

    final snapshot = await docMember.get();

    if (snapshot.exists) {
      return Member.fromJson(snapshot.data()!);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

and in my View I have this

```
  final mem = Auth().readLoggedMemberonly;
```

Now I want to access users data like **name**

I tried with

```
 child: Text(mem?.name), //name was declared in the model and it exits in the firestore users document
```

But got this error

[image]

this after removing **const** from **Drawer**

[image]

Comment: remove const from the Container containing Text(mem?.name)

Comment: @Chris done but that not the issue

Comment: what's the error then? ```Evaluation of this constant...``` only says about const somewhere

Comment: updated, kindly check

Comment: If you don't want to use a `FutureBuilder`, then how do you intend to deal with the fact that the data you want to display is loaded asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

```
  final mem = Auth().readLoggedMemberonly;
```

if you want to call a function you have to add brackets

```
  final mem = Auth().readLoggedMemberonly();
```

Then, its future, so probably you want to await for it

```
  final mem = await Auth().readLoggedMemberonly();
```

then you can use your value

```
  Text(mem?.name ?? '');
```

Comment: I got this error: **The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'**

Comment: yup, because wherever you call ```Auth().readLoggedMemberonly();``` the function must be marked with async. If you call it in the build method then you should probably look at Future and build your layout based on FutureBuilder. You can also call ```Auth().readLoggedMemberonly();``` in initState method and assign it to object member

Comment: sample please. 

I want to always call the function is many places in the app. I don't think FutureBuilder ia the solution unless there is another way to it.

Comment: what I actually want to do is to easily call user data like name, phone, country etc anywhere in the app without the need to write long code or re-writing functions. In php I normally save the data as cookie and call it anywhere or I declare a public function if the data changes often.